# How to have different text per button, rather than having it all the same

Tags: python, button, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to have 5 different buttons, each labelled A, B, C, D and E accordingly. So far I have:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
window = Tk()
for i in range (5):
    button = Button(window, text="A")
    button.grid(row=i//5, column=i%5)
window.mainloop()
```

However i cannot work out how to change the text for individual buttons.
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to iterate over the letters and the indices of the buttons:

```
for i, text in enumerate(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']):
    button = Button(window, text=text)
    button.grid(row=i//5, column=i%5)
```